# Getting error on adding angular-daterangepicker javascript files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular js code is as below. I am adding [DateRangePicker](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker) 
with following library

```js
var inApp = angular.module('myApp', ['daterangepicker']);

inApp.controller('incomeController', function($scope, $http) {
      console.log('income controller');
      $scope.datePicker = { date: {startDate: null, endDate: null} };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker/master/js/angular-daterangepicker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.css" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="incomeController">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="optsCustom" class="control-label">Select Date</label>
    <div>
      <input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker" type="text" ng-model="datePicker.date" />
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

It is showing following error

```
angular.js:14642 TypeError: r.daterangepicker is not a function
at h (angular-daterangepicker.min.js:1)
at angular-daterangepicker.min.js:1
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18210)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18480)
at done (angular.js:12501)
at completeRequest (angular.js:12727)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12655)
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Julien's answer is correct, but don't forget to change the controller name in your `ng-controller` tag to `incomeController`. This won't fix your problem, but your code won't work correctly otherwise!

Comment: updated controller name. angular.js:14642 TypeError: el.daterangepicker is not a function is error message

Comment: Yes, I told you it would not fix your problem.

Comment: Resolved this problem there was two jquery file. One jquery file was renamend to facing this problem

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using GitHub as a CDN (which is againt its terms of use).

The URL `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker/master/js/angular-daterangepicker.js` has a `Content-Type` at `text/plain; charset=utf-8`. It can't be used inside a `script` since it's neither `text/javascript` nor `application/javascript`.

More details here: https://github.blog/2013-04-24-heads-up-nosniff-header-support-coming-to-chrome-and-firefox/

Remark: you should use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`, in DEV environment since the error message is more clear:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module daterangepicker due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'daterangepicker' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: This is for creating working demo . I have included code in lib folder after download then also the problem?

Comment: Error is angular.js:14642 TypeError: el.daterangepicker is not a function

Comment: code is above that i am using included all files after download at my localhost there i am getting this error